# Writing a batch file to delete files with wildcards

Tags: batch-file, wildcard, dos

I have multiple websites set up in the same folder, and I want to create a batch file that will delete the cache in each of them without having to add a new line for each site. For example I am using this:

```
del /S /Q D:\www\site-name\cache\*
```

Which works, but I have to add a new line for every site in `D:\www`. The del command doesn't support:

```
del /S /Q D:\www\*\cache\*
```

So what is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
for /D %%f in ("D:\www\*") do @(
del /S /Q "%%f\cache\*"
)
```

Comment: You may also be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697885/how-to-delete-only-empty-directories-from-a-batch-file/11005370#11005370