# MS-DOS delete with wildcards on ends

Tags: batch-file, wildcard, dos

What I want is a wildcard that means "contains"
So if I have a directory with

```
a.txt
b.param
b.param.config
```

I would like to delete only `b.param` and `b.param.config`

I have tried `del *.param*`, `del *param*` ... but nothing seems to match anything for the beginning and end of the file but **containing** `param`.

I am running the command from a batch file, so if the solution is in batch that will work as well.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556778/writing-a-batch-file-to-delete-files-with-wildcards

Comment: saw that one...doesn't apply because i can't delete *EVERYTHING* in the directory

Comment: I tried, I will admit I didn't use DOS in a little while!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think del *param* should work for this...

```
c:\test>dir /w
 Volume in drive C is HP
 Volume Serial Number is 0EBF-B242

 Directory of c:\test

[.]              [..]             a.txt            b.param
b.param.config
               3 File(s)             29 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  185,518,833,664 bytes free

c:\test>dir /w *param*
 Volume in drive C is HP
 Volume Serial Number is 0EBF-B242

 Directory of c:\test

b.param          b.param.config
               2 File(s)             20 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  185,518,833,664 bytes free

c:\test>del *param*

c:\test>dir /w
 Volume in drive C is HP
 Volume Serial Number is 0EBF-B242

 Directory of c:\test

[.]     [..]    a.txt
               1 File(s)              9 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  185,518,833,664 bytes free
```

What happened when you tried this? What version of MS-DOS are you running?

Comment: I misspelled the middle character...time to go home for the night. lol